# parsing this data with beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I've pasted below some HTML data.  THis is not the entirety of the page.  There is a lot of other divs, etc, and stuff i don't need.  Below is the most relevant section for this example.

```
<div class="prox_sub22"><a onclick="return srpVehicleNameGAEvent();"
  data-bind="attr:{href:VehicleDetailUrl, id: GetVehicleTitleId()}, html:AN.DSF.Data.SearchObjects.GetShortenVehicleName(Year+' '+Make+' '+Model+' '+StyleName)"
  href="/new/2016/ford/expedition-el/king ranch/1FMJK1JTXGEF06926"
  id="Vehicle_Title_0">2016 Ford Expedition EL 4WD 4d...</a>
</div>
<div class="prod_vin txt11"><span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVinLabelId()}"
  id="VIN_Label_0">VIN:</span>
  <span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVehicleVinId()}, text:Vin"
  id="Vehicle_Vin_0">1FMJK1JTXGEF06926</span>
</div>
<div class="prox_sub22"><a onclick="return srpVehicleNameGAEvent();"
  data-bind="attr:{href:VehicleDetailUrl, id: GetVehicleTitleId()}, html:AN.DSF.Data.SearchObjects.GetShortenVehicleName(Year+' '+Make+' '+Model+' '+StyleName)"
  href="/new/2017/ford/super-duty-f--250-srw/xl/1FT7W2BT3HEC24765"
  id="Vehicle_Title_1">2017 Ford Super Duty F-250 SRW...</a>
</div>
<div class="prod_vin txt11"><span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVinLabelId()}"
  id="VIN_Label_1">VIN:</span>
  <span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVehicleVinId()}, text:Vin"
  id="Vehicle_Vin_1">1FT7W2BT3HEC24765</span>
</div>
```

i'm pasting only one small section of the HTML file for reference...there are 72 (inclduing 0) of these on the page.  I am trying to iterate through this page and get all the Vehicle_Vin on the page.

here's my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,"html.parser")
    stock = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "prod_vin txt11"})


    for j in range(0,72):

        vinlist = []

        for subvins in stock:
            vins = subvins.find_all("span", attrs={"id" : "Vehicle_Vin_{}".format(j)})
        for vin in vins:
            vinlist.append(vin.string)
        print(j,vinlist)
```

So the issue is that I keep getting a NULL list when this runs through and I can't seem to figure out why.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You may see this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396655/parsing-html-using-beautifulsoup-in-python

Comment: I guess there is a missing indentation in the line -> for vin in vins: vinlist.append(vin.string). This for loop should place inside the outer for loop.

Comment: thank you for that catch.  You're right, i should put that in the outer for loop.  However, why doesnt each new VIN get added to the list I created?  At the end I should have a list that has 72 items in it, but I only end up with a list with 1 item in it??

Answer (score 1):

i realize now that i needed to put the vinlist=[] outside of the for j in range() loop.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = """
<div class="prox_sub22"><a onclick="return srpVehicleNameGAEvent();" data-bind="attr:{href:VehicleDetailUrl, id: GetVehicleTitleId()}, html:AN.DSF.Data.SearchObjects.GetShortenVehicleName(Year+' '+Make+' '+Model+' '+StyleName)" href="/new/2016/ford/expedition-el/king ranch/1FMJK1JTXGEF06926" id="Vehicle_Title_0">2016 Ford Expedition EL 4WD 4d...</a></div>
  <div class="prod_vin txt11"><span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVinLabelId()}" id="VIN_Label_0">VIN:</span> <span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVehicleVinId()}, text:Vin" id="Vehicle_Vin_0">1FMJK1JTXGEF06926</span></div>
  <div class="prox_sub22"><a onclick="return srpVehicleNameGAEvent();" data-bind="attr:{href:VehicleDetailUrl, id: GetVehicleTitleId()}, html:AN.DSF.Data.SearchObjects.GetShortenVehicleName(Year+' '+Make+' '+Model+' '+StyleName)" href="/new/2017/ford/super-duty-f--250-srw/xl/1FT7W2BT3HEC24765" id="Vehicle_Title_1">2017 Ford Super Duty F-250 SRW...</a></div>
  <div class="prod_vin txt11"><span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVinLabelId()}" id="VIN_Label_1">VIN:</span> <span data-bind="attr:{ id: GetVehicleVinId()}, text:Vin" id="Vehicle_Vin_1">1FT7W2BT3HEC24765</span></div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc,'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all(id=re.compile(r"Vehicle_Title_\d+")):
    print(i.get('id'), i.get_text(), sep='\t\t')
```

out_put:

```
Vehicle_Title_0     2016 Ford Expedition EL 4WD 4d...
Vehicle_Title_1     2017 Ford Super Duty F-250 SRW...
```